# Commit/rollback transactions manually with multiple datasources in Micronaut

Tags: jdbc, datasource, micronaut, transactionmanager, micronaut-data

I need to commit/rollback transactions manually with multiple datasources in micronaut-data. But when commits second transaction(`db2TransactionManager.commit(db2Transaction)`) it throws below exception. How can I solve this problem or is there any other way, also I tried with defining `@Repository` and `@Transactional` etc., but there is other problem that commits transactions separately?

```console
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction synchronization is not active
        at io.micronaut.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.getSynchronizations(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:334)
        at io.micronaut.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:100)
        at io.micronaut.transaction.support.AbstractSynchronousTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronousTransactionManager.java:1011)
        at io.micronaut.transaction.support.AbstractSynchronousTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractSynchronousTransactionManager.java:863)
        at io.micronaut.transaction.support.AbstractSynchronousTransactionManager.commit(AbstractSynchronousTransactionManager.java:807)
```

**DemoService.java**

```java
@Singleton
public class DemoService {
    private final SynchronousTransactionManager<Connection> db1TransactionManager;
    private final SynchronousTransactionManager<Connection> db2TransactionManager;
    private final SynchronousTransactionManager<Connection> db3TransactionManager;

    @Inject
    public LogsterSynchronizerService(@Named("db1") SynchronousTransactionManager<Connection> db1TransactionManager,
                                      @Named("db2") SynchronousTransactionManager<Connection> db2TransactionManager,
                                      @Named("db3") SynchronousTransactionManager<Connection> db3TransactionManager) {
        this.db1TransactionManager = db1TransactionManager;
        this.db2TransactionManager = db2TransactionManager;
        this.db3TransactionManager = db3TransactionManager;
    }

    public void processRecords() {
        TransactionStatus<Connection> db1Transaction = db1TransactionManager.getTransaction(null);
        db1TransactionManager.executeWrite(status -> insertDb1(status.getConnection()));

        TransactionStatus<Connection> db2Transaction = db2TransactionManager.getTransaction(null);
        db2TransactionManager.executeWrite(status -> insertDb2(status.getConnection()));

        TransactionStatus<Connection> db3Transaction = db3TransactionManager.getTransaction(null);
        db3TransactionManager.executeWrite(status -> insertDb3(status.getConnection()));

        db1TransactionManager.commit(db1Transaction);
        db2TransactionManager.commit(db2Transaction);
        db3TransactionManager.commit(db3Transaction);
    }

    private int insertDb1(Connection db1Connection) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_demo(dt) VALUES (SYSTIMESTAMP)";
        PreparedStatement ps = db1Connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        return ps.executeUpdate();
    }

    private int insertDb2(Connection db2Connection) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_demo(dt) VALUES (SYSTIMESTAMP)";
        PreparedStatement ps = db2Connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        return ps.executeUpdate();
    }

    private int insertDb3(Connection db3Connection) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_demo(dt) VALUES (SYSTIMESTAMP)";
        PreparedStatement ps = db3Connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        return ps.executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

**application.yml**

```yml
micronaut:
  application:
    name: demo-app
datasources:
  db1:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@db1.demo.com:1521:db1
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    username: test
    password: test
    schema-generate: none
    dialect: ORACLE
    auto-commit: false
    maximum-pool-size: 3
    minimum-idle: 1
    idle-timeout: 5
  db2:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@db2.demo.com:1522:db2
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    username: test
    password: test
    schema-generate: none
    dialect: ORACLE
    auto-commit: false
    maximum-pool-size: 3
    minimum-idle: 1
    idle-timeout: 5
  db3:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@db3.demo.com:1522:db3
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    username: test
    password: test
    schema-generate: none
    dialect: ORACLE
    auto-commit: false
    maximum-pool-size: 3
    minimum-idle: 1
    idle-timeout: 5
netty:
  default:
    allocator:
      max-order: 3
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
...
  <properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
    <release.version>11</release.version>
    <micronaut.version>3.4.2</micronaut.version>
    <micronaut.data.version>3.3.0</micronaut.data.version>
    <exec.mainClass>com.demo.Application</exec.mainClass>
    <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
  </properties>
...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-data-jdbc</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
...
```